# AmazonS3ClientBuilder working with wrong credentials

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Seeing as s3 client class got depreciated, I am trying to use this new static class provided to us by aws and it's confusing me quite a bit. I am creating a new client and passing it some false credentials, yet it does not throw any errors. Am I missing something here?

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("uselessinfo", "abcd1234");

AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
    .withRegion(Regions.DEFAULT_REGION)
    .build();

s3Client.getS3AccountOwner();
```

Also, even when I give correct credentials the getS3AccountOwner() method is unable to make a connection and keeps timing out.

What am I missing here?

Comment: My guess is it doesn't actually use the credentials until you make a call.  I'm surprised it doesn't throw an exception on get account owner.  You possibly need to specify the region, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Are you using the AWS Java SDK v1 or v2? They are different.

Comment: @jarmod I am not sure but why would it make a difference? I see one api documentation

Comment: Timeouts generally indicate network connectivity problems. Where are you running this code? Is it by any chance on an EC2 instance in a private subnet that doesn't have a NAT?

Comment: Also, if you're getting an exception you should add it to the question. The _exact_ exception, copied from the terminal window where you're running the program, not your interpretation of the exception.